# Lifecycle State always INITIALIZED

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Im trying to call a custom dialog only if the app has started.

```
if (mGameActivity.getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) { 
     mDialogWinByLeft.show(mGameActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
}
```

But the current state is always INITIALIZED.
Im implementing the interface `LifecycleRegistryOwner` over `GameActivity`.

Sorry if I didnt understand well this new api.
Thanks

Comment: Got the same problem for appCompat Fragment. Pablo, do you know the solution for this?

Comment: No sorry, I have not used this api more

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description I would hazard a guess that you are checking the state in `onCreate`.  During the `onCreate` the lifecycle state is only `INITIALIZED`.

See this diagram from Google.
<strike>[Google Lifecycle State Diagram](https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle-states.png)</strike> (link broken but can be accessed on [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle-states.png))

That said you can use the annotation library to observe when you have entered the `STARTED` state.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.EVENT.ON_START)
void doSomething(){
    //do the thing that needs the lifecycle to be at least started
}
```

That said this is called **after** every onStart is finished. So it may be prudent to bake in some logic to determine if this is the appropriate time to do the things that need doing.

Also to make this code work, the class that is to observe the Lifecycle event must implement `LifecycleObserver`. This could be any class or even the Activity or Fragment itself. The below code is for a general class/module that will act as a Lifecycle observer.

```
public class LifeCycleObserverModule implements LifecycleObserver {
    LifeCycleObserverModule(Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        //register the life cycle to observe
        this.lifecycle = lifecycle;
        this.lifecycle.addObserver(this);
    }
}
```

If you were to make an Activity observe it's own Lifecycle it would be something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleObserver {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLifecycle().addObserver(this)
    }
}
```

For a fragment it works the same, but it could observer it's own Lifecycle or that of the activity. If you wanted it to observe the Activity's Lifecycle you could do this. Otherwise it would be the same way as you would do it for the Activity example above.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}
```

One final note, I am not entirely clear on if an Activity or Fragment observing it's own Lifecycle is best practice.  But it does work, and there seems to be no ill effects from doing so.  I am currently using the above method in a couple of Apps I am working on.

EDIT:  Corrected the example code. It used to say `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.EVENT.STARTED)` as was pointed out in a comment `STARTED` does not exist, the proper value was `ON_START`. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: This code doesn't work. Also there is no Lifecycle.Event "Started".

Comment: @SlavaSotone you are right. Not sure why I got that stuck in my head when I originally wrote this. Also I added a some more detailed code to show how to get the code to work.

Comment: Starting from appCompat 26.1 you don't need to create observer. To get lifecycle state for android.support.v4.app.Fragment or AppCompatActivity just use: lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.STATE.STARTED)

Comment: @SlavaSotone In my experience with the new Libraries, and unless this has changed... If you were to call lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.STATE.STARTED) in onCreate of an Activity it will return false, because during the execution of the onCreate method, the lifecycle is only "INITIALIZED".  This will however work on onCreateView for a fragment, because the activity reaches the started state before attaching fragments. In fact once a Fragment is attached the Activity's Lifecycle is "RESUMED". This is the reason you could use an observer.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you. I mentioned this point in my answer below. But the question is: should I perform a call after check state of activity/fragment during initialization? Maybe the better way is performing call in activity/fragment lifecycle methods, like onStart(), if you need to call something during initialization. @Azethoth

Comment: It worked at the time of the post. Looks like Google must have moved that diagram not sure where it is now but I can try to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation can be helpful to understand concept with example usage and graph: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc

Basic example with Kotlin:

```
if (lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
   //Do your work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle state could be INITIALIZED in case you check the state during first initialization, for example right after onStart() call.

After Activity or Fragment is fully initialized you can get appropriate lifecycle state.

So if you use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0, for android.support.v4.app.Fragment or AppCompatActivity use following:

```
lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.STATE.STARTED)
```

In most cases no need to create custom LifecycleObserver.